# Form the English alphabet using thirteen people

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, sequence

Thirteen well known people (some of them alive and some of them deceased) are numbered from 1 to 13.

---

Instead of revealing who they are, the following clues are provided:

1. An Italian football player.
2. An American Rapper.
3. A German classical scholar.
4. A Swedish politician.
5. A French-Swiss actress.
6. An English musician.
7. An American combat pilot.
8. A Russian author.
9. A Czech-American tennis player.
10. An American celebrity chef.
11. An American freelance writer.
12. An English naturalist.
13. An Italian race car driver.

---

When all these people are placed side-by-side in some specific order, they will complete the English alphabet (where all the letters will be in order while reading from left to right).

---

Here is a partially completed version of it:

[image]

---

***Fill up the empty blocks with the remaining numbers to complete it.***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution

> 1. An Italian football player. – [Sandro Tonali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandro_Tonali)
>  2. An American Rapper. – [Kendrick Lamar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendrick_Lamar)
>  3. A German classical scholar. – [Wilhelm Xylander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Xylander)
>  4. A Swedish politician. – [Olof Palme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olof_Palme)
>  5. A French-Swiss actress. – [Irene Jacob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irene_Jacob)
>  6. An English musician. – [George Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Harrison)
>  7. An American combat pilot. – [Quentin Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Roosevelt)
>  8. A Russian author. – [Yevgeny Zamyatin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yevgeny_Zamyatin)
>  9. A Czech-American tennis player. – [Martina Navrátilová](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martina_Navr%C3%A1tilov%C3%A1)
>  10. An American celebrity chef. – [Anthony Bourdain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Bourdain)
>  11. An American freelance writer. – [Ursula Vernon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_Vernon)
>  12. An English naturalist. – [Charles Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Darwin)
>  13. An Italian race car driver. – [Enzo Ferrari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzo_Ferrari)
>
>  In order:
>
> ```
>  10 12 13 06 05 02 09 04 07 01 11 03 08
>  AB CD EF GH IJ KL MN OP QR ST UV WX YZ
> ```

Solving notes

> There's a [handy website](https://memoempire.com/humans/initials/kl/) that allows you to search for famous people with the given initials. There are definitely some dead end paths – for example, I had [Quando Rondo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quando_Rondo) for #2 and [Gottfried Hermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Gottfried_Jakob_Hermann) for #3 for a while but had to change them around as the rest didn't work. It feels reasonably certain that these are the intended answers once you find a grouping with a valid answer for each number. The given numbers are a big help in fixing the correct order, like the #10 in the first cell immediately tells you that the celebrity chef has to be A.B. The hardest one for me to find was #7, because the fact that he was a combat pilot is often not the first thing mentioned about that person.